# How to manage time in Extreme Programming?

Tags: time, extreme-programming

I am monitoring a competition where each sprint is scheduled to one hour interval. Each team member should have a count down c'lock on the screen, preferrably on terminal. The c'locks should lauch alarm after 45 minutes, 55 minutes and and 60 minutes.

The enviroment should create a feeling of extreme programming. Is there some ready terminal application for the job?

**[Clarification]** The teams are using Ubuntus and Macs.

Comment: what is it? you conducting an exam or something? I can't see how you can achieve good quality software with such horrendous method. Its likely to irritate people than motivating them. Management would never understand it. And one hour sprint? Are you joking? We run 3 to 4 week sprints here in agile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, my first question is "good God, why?"  How can you do a sprint in an hour.

But having said that -- I presume it some classroom session or something -- there are a number of applications like that; mentioning the operating system might help narrow it down.

On Macs I'm fond of using *Miniteur*.

On a UNIX system, it's an ur-simple shell script (bash syntax here):

```
sleep $((45*60)) && echo "Forty five minutes"
sleep $((10*60)) && echo "FIVE MINUTES LEFT"
sleep $((5*60)) &&  echo 'TIME IS UP!'
```

Comment: Great thanks! I did not wait so simple answer :) I have to test it straight away.

Comment: A question emerged from experimenting, is it possible to have a beep-sound?

Comment: or flashing so that people would notice the alarm behind their terminal.

Comment: The beep is easy: use `echo -e '\a\a\a\a'` will make a nice one.  To flash the terminal, look at the ANSI control sequences for your particular terminal.

Comment: Yes, I got it beeping :) 
echo -e \\a
echo -e '\a'
echo -en '\x07'
echo -en "\x07"

Answer (score 3):

"...The enviroment should create a feeling of extreme programming...", I think this environment will create a feeling of extreme pressure, we're not flipping burgers here, we're doing something creative, give your team a break if they need to know what time it is, and how much of each hour is left they'll use their watches.

BTW has this approach been tried already? If so did it work? What did the team think of it?

Comment: Similar methods are used in IB Dibloma Programme examinations, where candidates have very little time. The students are highly-motivated and highly-skilled, and they have asked for New Challenges. Creativity needs always some aggregation.

Comment: The students are selected. Some of them have interest to finance. Some af them just like challenges. It is fascinating to see their rapid development.

Answer (score 1):

## WOW

There's one thing I really like while thinking about 1 hour sprints/iterations. If I think of the crazy pace of the sprint, the first thing that popped in my mind (to actually make anything done in this short timebox) is **pair programming** or even **team development**. The very essence of XP.

Which made me think. **The shorter the sprints the more you start using XP paradigm.** You start fast brainstorming within the team, pair program code (the fastest coder does it) and communicate a lot. Perfect XP.

Though in real life this short sprints are a killer to burn-out your team really quick. But you can learn a lot by thinking of it. And adopting results to natural sprint length (1 week).